# Apache mod rewrite rule not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make my links seo friendly, my current links are like this:

```
site.dev/al/?page=about
```

and I am trying to change it into this:

```
site.dev/al/about
```

Below you can see what I have been trying in my

> .htaccess

so far:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?page=$1 [L,NS]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ?page=$1 [L]
</ifModule>
```

This is my apache log message:

> [Wed Apr 05 20:35:44 2017] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded
>   the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration
>   error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if
>   necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this rule in **`<DocumentRoot>/al/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /al/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ ?page=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, you were perfectly right, absolutely awesome. If I had deeper links like ?page=about&kat=happy would I be able to just keep appending $ in the above rule to make the link: a/about/happy . Thank you again friend